# elasticsearch bool filter should clause performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, filter

first query:

```
  {        "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
          "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
               "must" : [
                   {"term" : {"user1_id" : "1"}}, 
                   {"range" : {"day" : {"gte" : "2015-04-01", "lte" : "2015-04-30"}}}
               ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

In relational SQL, the first query equals to SQL:

```
select * from table where user1_id =1 and (day>=2015-04-01 and day <= 2015-04-30)
```

Second query:

```
{           "query" : {
                "filtered" : {
                  "filter" : {
                    "bool" : {
                      "should" : [{"term"  : {"user1_id" : "1"}}, {"term" : {"user2_id" : "1"}}],
                      "must" : {"range" : {"day" : {"gte" : "2015-04-02", "lte" : "2015-04-30"}} },
                      "_cache" : true 
                    }
                  }
                }
              } }
```

In relational SQL, the second query equals to SQL:

```
select * from table where (user1_id =1 or user2_id = 1) and (day>=2015-04-01 and day <= 2015-04-30)
```

The difference is,

the first query only considers `user1_id`, while the second one also check `user2_id`.

both `user1_id` and `user2_id` are indexed.

However, the performance differs a lot.

the first query took 5 seconds, while the second one took 20 seconds.

Is there any better way for the second query?

Mapping:

```
   user1_id:
    type: "string"
    index: "not_analyzed"
    doc_values: true
   user2_id: 
     type: "string"
     index: "not_analyzed"
     doc_values: true
   day:
     type: "date"
     format: "YYYY-MM-dd"
    ignore_malformed: true
    doc_values: true
```

If I run the first query twice, the first time is `user1_id`, the second time is `user2_id`, then combine two results. It is much faster than using the second query.

Have 10 Billion documents in total. AWS, m2.4xlarge, 8 instances in total.

`/usr/bin/java -Xms30g -Xmx30g`

Comment: Can you show the mapping for the  `user_id` field? It's a string but is it `analyzed` or `not_analyzed`?

Comment: Yes. It is string, `not_analyzed`

Comment: I'm surprised by the execution time of your queries. Can you tell how many documents you have approximately and what kind of hardware you're running ES on?

Comment: 10 billion documents in total, I am on AWS, m2.4xlarge, 8 instances in total. /usr/bin/java -Xms30g -Xmx30g

Comment: Interesting data set, indeed. Can you tell us what is the match ratio for the `range` constraint, and same thing for `user1_id = 1` and `user2_id = 1`? (i.e. how many docs are in that range or have the given user id).

Comment: It is about one-month data. range filter is used. few docs, about twenty, for user1_id = 1 or user2_id = 1. It is or, not and. I tried other popular user ID, get similar results. Use bool filter should clause is slower...

Comment: each day is about 1/30 of the total data (10B). different user ID has different ratio. some are popular, for example, some user ID can have 20K activities. while some are inactive, for example, the user ID 1, it only has 20 activities.

Comment: How many users do you have? It is very likely that your memory is not enough to hold the filter cache, so it is evicting the cache hence taking more time. As an alternative try using AND/OR filter instead of the bool filters, using the user ID as the first filter. It is against the recommended practice wrt use of bitsets but AND filters are executed sequentially so the the result set will become smaller when it comes to filter by range.

Comment: make sense. I increased the filter cache to 20%. it returns faster. However, it is still slower than running twice with single user ID. There are over millions users. I do not know the exact number, but I am sure it is a lot. as you said, the bitset is large, it costs memory and takes time to bring to memory?

Comment: 20% might not be enough. Do you have the bigdesk plugin or Sense or HQ, or any other plugin that provides historical insights into filter cache evictions?

Comment: I used the built-in marvel. I checked the eviction rate for this index when I did the search. I did see the filter cache goes up. But the eviction rate is 0. I also checked every server (8 instances). only one of them show several evictions happened.

Comment: @chnet Filter cache eviction does really slow down search requests. Can you try `and`/`or` filters instead of `bool` filters? You can also try increasing the filter cache size.

Comment: tried to use AND/OR filter instead of bool filter. It is almost the same as bool, slightly better. The filter cache size is still 20%. The single user ID running twice still perform better than bool should clause and AND/OR. the single user ID running twice took about 5 seconds, while AND/OR took 8 seconds.

Comment: I think one benefit of running single userID twice is caching. The first run user1_id = 1 took 4 seconds, while the second run user2_id = 1 took less than 1 second. that said, the second run benefits from cache of the first run. While the bool should or AND/OR took about 8 seconds, it does not have such benefit..